# Find the range of the following differentiable function

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f: R\to R$ be a differentiable function defined by
$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{3} \right)=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3}$$  for all real $x$ and $y$ and $f'(2)=2$.

Then

(i) what is the range of $f(|x|)$ ?
(ii)what is the number of solutions of the equation $x^2+(f(|x|))^2=9$?

**Progress:**  (i)
 $f\left(\frac{x+y}{3} \right)=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3} \implies f'\left(\frac{x+y}{3} \right). \left(1+y'\right)=f'(x)+f'(y)$.
  I stuck here.How can I find the range? and how can I find the number of solutions?

**Edit:**

$f\left(\frac{x+y}{3} \right)=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3} \implies f'\left(\frac{x+y}{3} \right). \left(1+y'\right)=f'(x)+f'(y) y'$.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, let's get rid of 2, for I feel it would look a little simpler that way:
$$f(x)=g(x)+2\text{, then}\\
g\left({x+y\over3}\right)={g(x)+g(y)\over3}
$$
Now plug $0$ for both arguments, and you'll find out that $g(0)=0$.

Now plug $x$ and $2x$, and you'll see that $g(2x)=2g(x)$.

At this point we might start to suspect that our equation is in fact equivalent to [Cauchy's functional equation][1]. We may continue in this manner until our domain is shredded according to Hamel basis. If you don't like the taste of it, then skip this step. Anyway, one particular family of solutions was already obvious before it: $g(x)=kx$, or $\color{red}{f(x)=kx+2}$. (Plug it into your original equation to make sure it fits!)

Now, if you want your derivative *anywhere* to be 2, then $k=2$ .
f(x)= 2x +2
f(|x|)=2|x| + 2

Now the Range of f(|x|)= [2,$\infty$)
and the equation x$^{2}$+y$^{2}$$\left(=\{f\left(|x|\right)\}^{2}\right)$=3$^{2}$is
quadratic in x so it should have two solutions